# Impose some pattern over object key names in typescript type

Tags: typescript

In typescript, is it possible to declare a type stating that their properties have some given pattern, for example, they all end with the character `w`?

For this example, here is one such object that would comply with that type:

```
{
    "250w": ...,
    "1024w": ...,
    "300w": ...
}
```

The following object would not comply (with the example given above):

```
{
    "share": ...,
    "bound": ...,
    "cut": ...,
}
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
interface MyCrazyType {
   [key ????]: any;
}
```

Comment: Found an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type MyCrazyType = {
    [key: `${number}w`]: any
}
```

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Comment: prettier is complaining about this: `Parsing error: Type expected.(prettier/prettier)`

Answer (score 3):

With typescript 4.1 and template literal types you can to a limited degree. You could do something like

```
type alphaNumeric = 'a'|'b'|'c'|'d' //you can take this to the extreme of all letters and numbers
type specialPattern = `${alphaNumeric}${alphaNumeric}w` | `${alphaNumeric}w` //this is limited to less than 1000 combinations see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336

let a:specialPattern = 'ab' //typescript complains because it does not end with w
a = 'abw' //good
a = 'aw' //good
a = 'abcw' //bad - more than two characters in front of the w
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgNmAFjAcgVwLYQE4EsDGUAvFAOQykA+pARlafvQCalQD0bIA9mlPjADsowGAGtowRLgDOwrsMTQIAD2DYIWKFwBmsOHChwIwYDlmCmUAZhpmAsAChQkKNMj5c8AAowTOISQABgAkAN7wSKiYOAQAvmERyOhYePixAO6BUJRQIeEISdGpGVkckjJQFXC4GLimlsDyRtKykoJQAIwADD18XBg0uAK+uFwCstIQ0IgmYNIAXBwA5nWIaDQAdPj9bLX42FzSOsBsACrgEADK+7hgJ2Bo+mwALF0AzG8AbI6ORsCw8zcEA83l8pmwATIMDo7DYzgg0hudz6GDAcBgQ1ktn4aEmlX+TC4CKsXH+EAElnSqyg6UcMGIUJo6VYyy4XCYdIZ5GZsKWbI5DnpJHINHwPI4NBglgAtFAMFx1Ap2sB0vJ8MhsDB8ODZEMoNoDgJ-joFNB0kA)

For you specific case the type would be

```
type mMyCrazyType = Record<specialPattern,any>
```

Comment: Typescript is just getting more and more features every day lol. I hope they can sustain all those features

Comment: For this answer to be complete, it may be useful to tell OP how to actually obtain the type he wants. Something like `type MyCrazyType = Record<specialPattern,any>;`